# How to find and count the same strings in a data frame in R

Tags: r

If I have a categorical variable in my data frame (eg list of 100 colours) and their count is 5000+, how do I count the number of red colours, number of blue colours etc and store them?

Comment: Do you want to count how many of each existing color appears?  table(df$color) would do it, assuming your data frame `df` has a column `color`.  Or do want to categorize the 100 colors into more general types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way to do it using Base R is to use table function

```
df_new<-as.data.frame(table(df$color,df$count))
```

This will give you count by various colors.

Answer (score 0):

tidyverse solution

```
library( tidyverse )
df %>% group_by( color ) %>% summarise( number = n() )
```